# When does homeomorphism imply diffeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

In $R^n$, suppose $U$ and $V$ and two homeomorphic **open** sets. Then, is $U$ diffeomorphic to $V$?

If not, can we impose stronger conditions such that this true?

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are not always diffeomorphic.  I think your best best is to actually check the smoothness of both maps.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the thing to use is to take some closed manifolds which are homeo but not diffeo, embed them smoothly in the same Euclidean space and then take tubular neighborhoods. This gives an example. Another example is an exotic 4-d space which embeds in the standard 4-d space.

Answer (score 6):

Such examples exist already in dimension 4: Mike Freedman was the first to construct *small exotic $R^4$*, that is an open subset of the standard 4d space which is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $R^4$.

On the positive side, suppose that you have a manifold $M$ homotopy-equivalent to a finite CW-complex and $dim(M)\ne 4$, so that $H_3(M, Z_2)=0$. Then $M$ admits a unique PL (piecewise-linear) structure. A proof of this can be found in 
["The Hauptvermutung Book"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/haupt.pdf) or this [Rudyak's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AT/0105047). It is also in Kirby and Siebemnann's book, but it is virtually unreadable. Since in dimensions $\le 6$ the categories PL and DIFF are equivalent, it follows that for domains in $R^5$ and $R^6$, if 3rd homology vanishes then homeomorphism implies diffeomorphism. A similar statement holds in other dimensions, when you want to show that homeomorphic manifolds are diffeomorphic. However, the obstructions are more complicated, the sufficient condition is that if you have an $n$-manifold $M$ ($n\ne 4$) which is homotopy-equivalent to finite CW complex and $H_k(M)=0$ ($k\ge 3$) then $M$ admits a unique smooth structure. For this, the only reference I know is [Kirby and Siebemnann's book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ks.pdf), but, as I said, it is essentially unreadable (the result is not even stated there in this form, you have to slog your way through Essay IV to make this conclusion).

Comment: can you please give a reference for the homology statement?

Answer (score 2):

There is a notion of categories: smooth, piecewise linear and topological spaces. In each of the categories there is a notion of equivalence (or sameness). For smooth we have diffeomorphism, Piece-wise linear is piece-wise linear homeomorphism and topological is homeomorphism. These three are not thesame in general. However in low-dimensional topology (dimensions less than 4), they are all equivalent.

Comment: Isn't Alexander's horned sphere homeomorphic to a $2$-spbere but not diffeomorphic to it?

Comment: @tomasz: this is good example but not relevant for this question. A smooth structure is defined via an atlas, not a topological embedding. However, Freedman's work can be regarded as a generalization if Alexander's construction in 4d.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part about the sets in question being open. Never mind. :)

Comment: consider $C$ is the graph of function $f(x)=|x|$. Geometrically, C is not smooth at the origin $(0,0)$. Howerver  $C$  is still homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and therefore one can define a smooth structure for $C$ such that $C$ is diffeomorphism to $\mathbb R$ in this sense, right ?